# Show Statistical Information on Regression Plot

Tags: python, statistics, regression, seaborn, pairplot

The below code used for regression plot and now I am wondering how can I estimate and print some statistical variables such as correlation, s-square and p value on each plot?

The second problem is how can I change plot color? For example how can I convert it from blue to red?

code link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jFy2iCywVQB3Ghq52phZlmGSr7bPFib5?usp=sharing

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from google.colab import files
data = files.upload()

from pandas.io import excel 
import io
df = pd.read_excel(data['yieldDataset.xlsx'])
df

data1 = df.drop({'Date','class'},1)

from sklearn import preprocessing
names = data1.columns
scalar = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
data2 = scalar.fit_transform(data1)
normal = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = names)
normal['class'] = df['class']
normal

import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.pairplot(normal, kind = 'reg')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your first question, I don't believe Seaborn can calculate correlation coefficients or p-values, but you can use an external package to calculate these (for example, Pandas can do correlation via the `corr` DataFrame method) and then annotate your plot.

To the second question, as explained in the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) you can pass arguments the bivariate and univariate plots respectively via the `plot` and `diagonal` arguments, so in your case:

```
sns.pairplot(...  plot_kws={'color': 'red'}, diag_kws={'color': 'red'})
```